# Notice: Array to string conversion in shipping delivery on magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, sql

I upgraded from magento 2.2.2 to 2.2.11 since I have an error when selecting a shipping address.

I get the error: "Notice: Array to string conversion in mywebsite/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3043".

[image]

But this error is present only when it is an address registered in the database, if I add an address it will work.

I've searched for the value that causes the problem.

In the logs I managed to get this :

```
INFO (6): array (
  'region_code' => NULL,
  'region' => NULL,
  'region_id' => 0,
)
```

I tried to find out where the region values were retrieved from. To not have them because they are useless to me and are all empty or equal to Null.

Comment: You mean, you downgraded?

Comment: No It's an upgrade 2.2.2 to 2.2.11

Comment: OpenSource to Commerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have resolve my problem.

For this I have create a plugin on WebSite/Cost/Plugin/Total/Quote/Credit.php

With **fixQuoteRegion**

```
    <?php

namespace WebSite\Cost\Plugin\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Mirasvit\Credit\Model\Config;
use Mirasvit\Credit\Model\BalanceFactory;
use Mirasvit\Credit\Helper\Calculation;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data as PricingHelper;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total as AddressTotal;


class Credit
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $processedShippingAddresses = [];

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $amountUsed = 0;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $baseAmountUsed = 0;
    /**
     * @var Calculation
     */
    private $calculationHelper;

    public function __construct(
        Calculation $calculationHelper,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $currencyHelper,
        \Mirasvit\Credit\Model\BalanceFactory $balanceFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
        Config $config
    ) {
        $this->calculationHelper = $calculationHelper;
        $this->currencyHelper    = $currencyHelper;
        $this->balanceFactory    = $balanceFactory;
        $this->checkoutHelper    = $checkoutHelper;
        $this->config            = $config;
        $this->_order            = $order;

    }

    /**
     * @param \Mirasvit\Credit\Model\Total\Quote\Credit $subject
     * @param $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    public function aroundCollect(
        \Mirasvit\Credit\Model\Total\Quote\Credit $subject,
        $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();

        $this->fixQuoteRegion($quote);

        if ($quote->getUseCredit() == Config::USE_CREDIT_NO) {
            $address->setBaseCreditAmount(0) //fix credit in address when no use anymore
                ->setCreditAmount(0)
                ->save();
            return $this;
        }


        if ($quote->getUseCredit() == Config::USE_CREDIT_UNDEFINED && !$this->config->isAutoApplyEnabled()) {
            $address->setBaseCreditAmount(0) //fix credit in address when no use anymore
                ->setCreditAmount(0)
                ->save();
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$quote->getCustomer() || !$quote->getCustomer()->getId()) {
            $address->setBaseCreditAmount(0) //fix credit in address when no use anymore
                ->setCreditAmount(0)
                ->save();
            return $this;
        }

        $quote->setUseCredit(Config::USE_CREDIT_YES);



        $quote->setBaseCreditAmountUsed(0)
            ->setCreditAmountUsed(0)
            ->save();

        $this->resetMultishippingTotalsOnRecollection($quote, $address->getId());

        $baseUsed = $this->balanceFactory->create()
            ->loadByCustomer($quote->getCustomerId(), $this->_order->getOrderCurrency())
            ->getAmount();
        $used = $this->currencyHelper->currency($baseUsed, false, false);

        $customerUsed     = $used;
        $customerBaseUsed = $baseUsed;
        if ($quote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
            $used     -= $this->amountUsed;
            $baseUsed -= $this->baseAmountUsed;
        } else {
            $this->amountUsed     = $used;
            $this->baseAmountUsed = $baseUsed;
        }

        if ($used > $total->getGrandTotal() && /*(float)$total->getGrandTotal() &&*/ $total->getGrandTotal() >= 0) {
            $used     = $total->getGrandTotal();
            $baseUsed = $total->getBaseGrandTotal();
        }

        $maxUsed     = $this->calculationHelper->calc(
            $total->getGrandTotal(), $total->getTotalAmount('tax'), $total->getTotalAmount('shipping')
        );
        if ($maxUsed < $used) {
            $used = $maxUsed;
        }
        if ($maxUsed < $baseUsed) {
            $baseUsed = $maxUsed;
        }

        if ($quote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
            $this->amountUsed     += $used;
            $this->baseAmountUsed += $baseUsed;

            if ($this->amountUsed > $customerUsed) {
                $this->amountUsed     = $customerUsed;
                $this->baseAmountUsed = $customerBaseUsed;
            }

            $this->processedShippingAddresses[$address->getId()] = $used;
        }

        //Overload : Allow to place order and not refill thr storeCredit if credit < 0
        if($quote->getIgnoreNegatif() == true){
            $used     = $total->getGrandTotal();
            $baseUsed = $total->getBaseGrandTotal();
            $this->amountUsed = $total->getGrandTotal();
            $this->baseAmountUsed = $total->getBaseGrandTotal();
        }

        $quote->setBaseCreditAmountUsed($this->baseAmountUsed)
            ->setCreditAmountUsed($this->amountUsed);

        $address->setBaseCreditAmount($baseUsed)
            ->setCreditAmount($used)
            ->save();

        $total->setBaseTotalAmount($subject->getCode(), $baseUsed);
        $total->setTotalAmount($subject->getCode(), $used);

        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseUsed);
        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() - $used);

        $total->setBaseCreditAmount($baseUsed);
        $total->setCreditAmount($used);

        $quote->setCreditCollected(true)
            ->save();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param int                        $addressId
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetMultishippingTotalsOnRecollection($quote, $addressId)
    {
        if (
            $quote->getIsMultiShipping()
            && !empty($this->processedShippingAddresses[$addressId])
            && $this->amountUsed
        ) {
            $this->amountUsed = 0;
            $this->processedShippingAddresses = [];
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function fixQuoteRegion($quote)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region $region */
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Version $region */
        $region = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getRegion();
        if ($region instanceof \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region) {
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setRegion($region->getRegion());
        } elseif (is_array($region)) { //M2.2.x
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setRegion($region['region'] ?: '');
        }
        $region = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getRegion();
        if ($region instanceof \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region) {
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setRegion($region->getRegion());
        } elseif (is_array($region)) { //M2.2.x
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setRegion($region['region'] ?: '');
        }
    }
}
```